# how can group UTC dates by date YYY-MM-DD?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of utc dates like:

```
[
 {createdAt: '2022-01-19T22:15:33.008Z'},
 {createdAt: '2022-01-19T21:15:33.008Z'},
 {createdAt: '2022-01-19T10:15:33.008Z'},
 {createdAt: '2022-01-20T23:15:33.008Z'},
 {createdAt: '2022-01-21T23:15:33.008Z'},
 {createdAt: '2022-01-22T23:15:33.008Z'},
 {createdAt: '2022-01-18T23:15:33.008Z'},
]
```

My desired output is:

```
{
  "2022-01-19":[
    {createdAt: '2022-01-19T22:15:33.008Z'},
    {createdAt: '2022-01-19T21:15:33.008Z'},
    {createdAt: '2022-01-19T10:15:33.008Z'}
  ],
   "2022-01-20":[
    {createdAt: '2022-01-20T23:15:33.008Z'},
  ],
   "2022-01-21":[
    {createdAt: '2022-01-21T23:15:33.008Z'},
  ],
   "2022-01-22":[
   {createdAt: '2022-01-22T23:15:33.008Z'},
  ],
   "2022-01-18":[
    {createdAt: '2022-01-18T23:15:33.008Z'},
  ],

}
```

I don't know if there is any date management function to get the YYYYY-MM-DD of a timestamp. how can I do it?

Comment: you can't use same keys in the object

Comment: @NITHINPB, it's an array of objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let tab = [
 {createdAt: '2022-01-19T22:15:33.008Z'},
 {createdAt: '2022-01-19T21:15:33.008Z'},
 {createdAt: '2022-01-19T10:15:33.008Z'},
 {createdAt: '2022-01-20T23:15:33.008Z'},
 {createdAt: '2022-01-21T23:15:33.008Z'},
 {createdAt: '2022-01-22T23:15:33.008Z'},
 {createdAt: '2022-01-18T23:15:33.008Z'},
]
let output = {};
tab.forEach(element => {
  let date = element.createdAt.split('T')[0];
  if (output[date] == undefined) {

    output[date] = []
  }
  output[date].push(element)
});

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split the string by the character 'T', then get the first item in the array to convert the string into the correct format.

Then, you can use [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to construct the object:

```js
let arr = [
 {createdAt: '2022-01-19T22:15:33.008Z'},
 {createdAt: '2022-01-19T21:15:33.008Z'},
 {createdAt: '2022-01-19T10:15:33.008Z'},
 {createdAt: '2022-01-20T23:15:33.008Z'},
 {createdAt: '2022-01-21T23:15:33.008Z'},
 {createdAt: '2022-01-22T23:15:33.008Z'},
 {createdAt: '2022-01-18T23:15:33.008Z'},
]

const res = arr.reduce((a,b) => {
  let date = b.createdAt.split("T")[0];
  if(!a[date]){
    a[date] = [];
  }
  a[date].push(b);
  return a;
}, {})

console.log(res)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100%!important;
  top: 0
}
```